# put xsl:element into a variable

Tags: sharepoint, xslt-1.0

Is there a way to put the output of SharePoint:AttachmentsField element into a variable?  I tried below but menuItemArrachments result in blank.

```
<td>
    <xsl:variable name="menuItemAttachments">
        <xsl:element name="SharePoint:AttachmentsField">
            <xsl:attribute name="runat">server</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="FieldName">Attachments</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="Visible">true</xsl:attribute>    
            <xsl:attribute name="ControlMode">Display</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="ItemId">
                <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:variable>  
    <xsl:value-of select="$menuItemAttachments" />  <!-- produces blank -->
</td>
```

without using variable, same code below produces a list of sharepoint attachment files:

```
<td>
     <xsl:element name="SharePoint:AttachmentsField">
        <xsl:attribute name="runat">server</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="FieldName">Attachments</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Visible">true</xsl:attribute>    
        <xsl:attribute name="ControlMode">Display</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="ItemId">
            <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
</td>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "result in blank"?

Comment: When I do <xsl:value-of select="$menuItemAttachments" />, it displayed blank.

Comment: Is the `value-of` supposed to return a node-tree or a text? The former may be difficult in XSLT 1.0 unless you have access to some extensions.

Comment: Could you try `<xsl:copy-of select='$menuItemAttachments'/>` instead of `value-of`?